# HttpPostedFileBase set image path?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an image on path `~/Imagens/Empresas/empresa.png` and I want to set this path to an attribute `HttpPostedFileBase` on model. How could I do this ?

trying.

```
public class EmpresaModel {

 [Required(ErrorMessage="Informe a imagem")]
    [FileExtensions("jpg|jpeg|png", MaxContentLength = 200000, ErrorMessage="Imagem inválida")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase imagem { get; set; }

}
```

Trying to use

```
String pathImage = Server.MapPath("~/Imagens/Empresas/empresa.png");
model.imagem.InputStream = new FileStream(pathImage, FileMode.Open);
```

Comment: You cant. You cannot set the value of a `HttpPostedFileBase` programatically for securityreasons. The only way it can be set is by the user selecting a file in the browser.

Comment: great, thanks a lot !

Comment: user3559349..but in my case, the User chooses not to select and I want to default to an image and therefore set that value of HttpPostedFileBase.